# Hidden tabs are lost after Excel Upgrade

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have created several workbooks that have data connections being used in sheets that I have hidden so that the end user doesn't have to see that data. Recently our office upgraded Excel versions and I cannot access those tabs any longer. I know they are there because connection properties has a new tab called Used-In. Inside that tab it shows where the connection property is located and it clearly indicates the tab I created for it but when I try to unhide the tab it doesn't show up.

I can also not find the table mentioned in the picture below either.

These tables are used in pivot tables and all the functionality works I just cant get to the data any longer.

What am I missing?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this in the Visual Basic Editor (*ALT + F11*):

Look for the sheet name and click on it. Under the Properties Tab (*press F4 if not showing*), check the Visible Property and change it to xlSheetVisible.

[image]

Comment: Thanks.. I kind of want to delete this post because right after I edited it the last time I went to my VBA I wrote a couple of years ago. Where I found that I had VERY HIDDEN them in the auto run macro. But I suppose I will leave it up here for someone else who might do something as dumb as me :)

Comment: It happens to the best of us. :)